# Python Redefine the variable given as a parameter to the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hello I am trying to make theme window with tkinter. There is 5 variable for different widgets's color. I will use color dialog for choosing colors but I don't want to define 5 functions. So I think I can make 1 function with 1 parameter of which variable to change color of it. My code is below;

My variables:

```
generalBgColor = '#454b4d'
generalFgColor = '#f2fdff'
generalBtnColor = '#0a5e7a'
mainLabelColor = '#ffffff'
highlightedLetterColor = '#ff0000'
```

Buttons that call `pickColor` function:

```
bgButton = tk.Button(themeWindow, text=' ', relief='ridge',
                         bg=generalBgColor, width=6, command=lambda: pickColor(generalBgColor))

fgButton = tk.Button(themeWindow, text=' ', relief='ridge',
                         bg=generalFgColor, width=6, command=lambda: pickColor(generalFgColor))

btnButton = tk.Button(themeWindow, text=' ', relief='ridge',
                          bg=generalBtnColor, width=6, command=lambda: pickColor(generalBtnColor))

mainlButton = tk.Button(themeWindow, text=' ', relief='ridge',
                            bg=mainLabelColor, width=6, command=lambda: pickColor(mainLabelColor))

letterButton = tk.Button(themeWindow, text=' ', relief='ridge',
                             bg=highlightedLetterColor, width=6,
                             command=lambda:pickColor(highlightedLetterColor))
```

And this is the my function:

```
def pickColor(variable):
        global generalBgColor, generalFgColor, generalBtnColor, mainLabelColor, highlightedLetterColor
        tempColor = askcolor(color=variable, title='Choose A Color')
        variable = tempColor[1]
```

There is no error but variable doesn't change.
I know this won't work this is the reason why I ask here for help.

Comment: You can use `<Widget>.config(bg=...)`.

Comment: but there is no one or two widgets, lot of them

Comment: The parameter `variable` is a *local* variable initialized with a *value* resulting from the evaluation of the argument passed to the function. There is no link between the parameter and any variables used to initialize it. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: Have you considered using a dict instead of five separate variables?

Comment: The variable is not passed to the function, only the value it held.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkinter natively supports color palette with [tk_setPalette](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/palette.htm). Be aware that the name and value pairs are for tk.widgets only and doesn't support ttk.widgets. In addition one has to define the palette before creating any other widgets and the `background` option is a positional argument that must be set. According to the docs, the following options are currently supported:

```
> activeBackground
> foreground
> selectColor
> activeForeground  
> highlightBackground
> selectBackground
> background
> highlightColor    
> selectForeground
> disabledForeground    
> insertBackground  
> troughColor
```

a minimal exempel is given in the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.tk_setPalette(background='#ff00f0',foreground='white')
tk.Label(root, text='test').pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively you always can specify a dictionary and like

```
my_options = {'background':'#000000'}
```

and unpack these in the constructor like `tk.Label(root, **my_options)`