# Tkinter - Update All Widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I am trying to change background by button on tkinter. I have a button that changes background of mainWindow but when button pressed it doesn't change immediately. I think `tk.update()` command is useless because I made too much test with it and nothing happened.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def ChangeBg():
    global bgColor
    bgColor = 'white'
    mainWindow.update()

bgColor = 'black'

root = tk.Tk()
mainWindow = tkToplevel()
mainWindow.geometry('500x500')

mainWindow.config(bg=bgColor)

btn = tk.Button(mainWindow, text='change background', command=ChangeBg)
btn.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

I guess you will say "Why don't you just use `mainWindow.config(bg=bgColor)`?". Because in my main code I have to store color in variables and there will be a lot more widgets. Like `generalBtnColor, generalForeground, generalTextColor`. I can write a lot of codes for update all widgets itself but this is Python and I believe there is a short way.

Comment: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662778/13629335) helps and let me know if there are open questions to the code I wrote and did not answer there.

Comment: Why do you think that modifying `bgColor` will change the window?

Comment: Because I used mainWindow.update()?

Comment: that was for changing a lot of local variables in a function and I handled it but I dont want to use tkinter default color pallete because it is same for every widgets. Example you have delete button and save button. Do you want to make them both red or green?

Comment: I suspect that your mental model of how `tkinter` works does not correspond with reality.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that you asked the linked question about the same topic. Neither you have asked questions to the code, nor did you told me why it doesnt answer your question. What are you hoping for by asking the same question over and over again?

Comment: @Seminet `.update` is quite different from what you imagine. You should rarely need to use it. Instead use: `mainWindow.config(bg="white")`

Comment: @TheLizzard Yes this is what am i asking for. Google with my bad english cant find proper things. I made about 10 search about update() but didnt find something helpfull.

Comment: tkToplevel() to tk.Toplevel()

Comment: It is nothing related to whether `update()` is executed or not.  The main issue is that updating a simple variable `bgColor` will not automatically update the background color of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `mainWindow.config(bg='white')`. Also changed in line 11 and 14.

```
import tkinter as tk


def ChangeBg():
    global bgColor
    mainWindow.config(bg='white')
    mainWindow.update()
    


root = tk.Tk()
mainWindow = tk.Toplevel()
mainWindow.geometry('500x500')

mainWindow.config(bg = 'black')

btn = tk.Button(mainWindow, text='change background', command=ChangeBg)
btn.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Output:
Current black:

[image]

After changing to white:

[image]